# Jquery - replace a hover event of a class through a new added class

Tags: jquery

I seach for a solution for the following problem, please can anyone help?

If the class .menu-link is hovered the subsequent function is performed . . .

```
<script>
var $content= $('li.menuDescription');
var $links=$('.menu-link').hover(function(){
   /* "this" is element being hovered*/
   var index= $links.index(this);
   $content.stop().hide().eq(index).show(); 
},function(){
   /* not sure if you want to leave current content visible if user leaves menu, if so do nothing here*/
})
</script>
```

And there is a second script which adds a new class:

```
$row.find("a").addClass("hovered");
```

Now I want to use for the first script instead of

```
('.menu-link').hover
```

only the new added class ".hovered" for the subsequent function, without that a hover event occurs. Is this possible?

Many Greetings

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use event delegation, because of the dynamic nature of the selector

```
var $content = $('li.menuDescription');
var $links = $('.menu-link')

$(document).on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        /* "this" is element being hovered*/
        var index = $links.index(this);
        $content.stop().hide().eq(index).show();
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        /* not sure if you want to leave current content visible if user leaves menu, if so do nothing here*/
    }
}, '.menu-link:not(.hovered)')
```

Comment: Thank you very much! It works with the usually function of the script, unfortunately the .hovered class of the second script isn't included, thus the hover function is only given if the html element is hovered in the usually way. Many Greetings